# Searching for a good year picker dropdown package in react js. I tried react-year-picker but the library has some bugs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, select, drop-down-menu

A year picker dropdown in react.js which can return year as an integer. react-year-picker has some bugs that need to be fixed. Kindly suggest if you know one. Is it possible by using the Datepicker package? 
If yes can someone show me how.
Thank you.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Here's the MUI 5 year picker code. Link to CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/year-picker-in-js-z1cw28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### react-datetime

[react-datetime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime) is the best option for you. I was able to integrate it in latest react version with no issues. The authors keep this package managed as well.

Check out the repl.it example I created for you:

**Code** : https://repl.it/@RAnis/reactDatePickerExample

**Demo** : https://reactdatepickerexample.ranis.repl.co/

**Edit** :
I used latest React version with hooks (useState), but it can be used with class components as well

Comment: thanks mate, this is exactly what i needed :)